# How do I group records to have one record per date with a column that has various alphabets?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sample table:

```
date    |  name  | record  
7/27/16 | john   | H  
7/27/16 | john   | P  
7/28/16 | john   | P  
7/28/16 | john   | L
```

Results:

```
date    |  name  | record  
7/27/16 | john   | H,P  
7/27/16 | john   | H,L
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    date, name, record 
FROM
    TABLE 
GROUP BY 
    date, name, record(not sure how to do this part)
```

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Oh Sorry, it is SQL Server.